How to get or convert to +12V from -48V telecom power supply rail
I want to convert the -48V from rectifier output of telecom equipment to +12V DC.
I'm considering the following schematic for that purpose:

The rectifier controller has -48V DC and +VE DC bus bar, the layout is pictured below:

How can I get the -48V from busbar as an input to LM2576HV?

Do you want the +12V to be referenced to the positive or the negative side of the 48V supply?

Basically I want to run a microcontroller,  sensors, and provide boolean output (+5V), but I'm not sure about +12V to be referenced to the positive or the negative

If you will be referencing to "ground", that would be the positive side of the telecom supply. You could take the -48V almost from anywhere that is safe and easy to tap into, but you should place a low value fuse like maybe 1A or even less.  Then you could use an IC like the old LT1082. There are actually many to choose from, it also depends on what can you get. If I get the time, I will give you a simple shcematic to work with your IC on hand.

That wil be so much helpful and appreciated.

@EdinFifić, where should I place fuse? in negative side or positive side of telecom power?

I think on the negative side, just like you have fuses on the right side of the schematic. Depending on what do you want to sense or measure, and will you interface your circuit with, you could use either negative or positive side, more needs to be known.
